# How do I make sbt fetch a repo published to my bintray repository?

Tags: scala, sbt, bintray

I uploaded a package using [bintray](https://github.com/softprops/bintray-sbt) and the sbt "publish" command...

```
[info]  delivering ivy file to /home/johnreed/sbtProjects/scala-trace-debug/target/scala-2.11/ivy-0.1.1.xml
[info] Wrote /home/johnreed/sbtProjects/scala-trace-debug/target/scala-2.11/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1.pom
[info] Packaging /home/johnreed/sbtProjects/scala-trace-debug/target/scala-2.11/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published scala-trace-debug_2.11 to https://api.bintray.com/maven/johnreed2/maven/maven/scala-trace-debug/scala-trace-debug_2.11/0.1.1/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1.pom
[info]  published scala-trace-debug_2.11 to https://api.bintray.com/maven/johnreed2/maven/maven/scala-trace-debug/scala-trace-debug_2.11/0.1.1/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1.jar
[info]  published scala-trace-debug_2.11 to https://api.bintray.com/maven/johnreed2/maven/maven/scala-trace-debug/scala-trace-debug_2.11/0.1.1/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1-sources.jar
[info]  published scala-trace-debug_2.11 to https://api.bintray.com/maven/johnreed2/maven/maven/scala-trace-debug/scala-trace-debug_2.11/0.1.1/scala-trace-debug_2.11-0.1.1-javadoc.jar
[info] johnreed2/scala-trace-debug@0.1.1 was released
[success]
```

Here is my Maven pom file that was generated...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>scala-trace-debug</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-trace-debug_2.11</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>scala-trace-debug</description>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache-2.0</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <name>scala-trace-debug</name>
    <organization>
        <name>scala-trace-debug</name>
    </organization>
    ...
```

^ I want to include [this published sbt project](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug) into another sbt project.

I try to add it to my other project's build.sbt file:

```
// Format: libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision

libraryDependencies += "scala-trace-debug" % "scala-trace-debug_2.11" % "0.1.1"
```

But it doesn't work.

I get this:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.9 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: scala-trace-debug#scala-trace-debug_2.11;0.1.1: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: scala-trace-debug#scala-trace-debug_2.11;0.1.1: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Mar 25, 2016 5:17:01 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/home/johnreed/.IdeaIC2016.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">/home/johnreed/.IdeaIC2016.1/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

How do I get sbt to fetch the repo published to my bintray repository?

Answer (score 2):

try to add similar settings on your `build.sbt` (one of them should be enough, depending on how you published it)

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("username", "maven")
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a resolver.

```
resolvers += "johnreed2 bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/content/johnreed2/maven"

libraryDependencies += "scala-trace-debug" % "scala-trace-debug_2.11" % "0.1.1"
```

Comment: depending on the sbt version, bintrayRepo may be already available. check my answer: `resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("username", "maven")`